# simple spark-submit job fails on EMR 5.5.0 with FileNotFoundException for __spark_config__.zip on HDFS

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I'm trying to deploy run a Python 3 Spark application on AWS ERM 5.5.0. I read a few articles on how to configure the cluster to require Python 3. I want to test that is getting set correctly so I created a simple application to print `sys.version`. Then I submit this job to the cluster.

When I run it on the master using either `spark-submit --deploy-mode client /local/path/to/version.py` or by submitting a step in client mode, it works and I see the version info (Python 3, yay!) on stdout.

When I run on the cluster (1 master, 1 core) using `spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster /local/path/to/version.py` or by submitting a step in cluster mode, it fails. The stderr log from the job says "Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1" in a few places. Looking this up, I was directed to `yarn logs` for the actual container logs. Looking at those, I see sets of logs for two containers.

In the stdout log for container container_1496243466754_0004_01_000001, I see that my actual python code ran and reported the python version (Python 3, yay again!). Since the code ran, I would expect the job to be a success, but it is not.

The logs from the other container container_1496243466754_0004_02_000001 show the following at the end of the stderr log:

```
17/05/31 17:11:58 INFO ApplicationMaster: Preparing Local resources
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://ip-10-0-210-27.hwheel.in:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1496243466754_0004/__spark_conf__.zip
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1309)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$6.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$6.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:157)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.<init>(ApplicationMaster.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:765)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
```

I think that is causing my job to fail. Skipping back to stderr from the other container, I see:

```
17/05/31 17:11:52 INFO ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory hdfs://ip-10-0-210-27.hwheel.in:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1496243466754_0004
```

So it appears to me that container_1496243466754_0004_01_000001 deleted the staging directory from HDFS when the application completes, but this trips up the other container that is then looking for a file in that directory 6 seconds later.

I've seen some (probably dated) explanations that this kind of error can occur due to Java version mismatches (apps in Java 8, spark in Java 7). However, I believe EMR runs all in Java 8 and that is the default on the cluster and I am not calling Java directly in my application.

How do I resolve this? Is my application just completing and deleting the staging files too quickly (it is just a single line of python)?

UPDATES:

- I added in a time.sleep(10) at the end of my one line program to make sure it was not a case of my program completing too quickly. No difference.
- I found documentation for spark.yarn.preserve.staging.files. I set this to true in spark-defaults.conf. I ran the same job again in cluster mode. This time both, containers run to completion w/ no errors. No problem w/ FileNotFound for **spark_conf**.zip. I can verify this file exists at the expected location on HDFS. However, the overall job still reports as failure `Application application_1496243466754_0007 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1496243466754_0007_000002 exited with exitCode: 0`. '0' seems like the correct exit code and the log files show no errors. Now I have no idea why the job is failing.

Comment: you can see this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905224/spark-shell-spark-libs-zip-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error. Reading your question I realized the one thing we have in common is that I also have a 2 node cluster with 1 master and 1 core. Repeating my work on a 3 node cluster (EMR's default) cause the problem to go away. If this solves your problem too and is the actual solution then there might be a bug or limitation with the minimum number of nodes/cluster for cluster deploy mode, at least on EMR.

Comment: I forgot I had posted this question. I moved on to running my actual spark job (on a larger cluster). Now, I can't recall if I actually resolved the issue above or just sidestepped it and was lucky enough not to see it in my actual job. I will go back and look to see if I can figure out if I solved it (and how).