# Google dataproc spark jobs failing with "Node was restarted while executing a job." message

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running multiple dataproc clusters for various spark streaming jobs. All clusters are configured as single node.

Recently (cca 10 days ago) i started to experience job failures on all clusters. Each job is running for approx. 3 days then fail with the same message:

```
=========== Cloud Dataproc Agent Error ===========
com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentException: Node was restarted while executing a job. This could be user-initiated or caused by Compute Engine maintenance event. (TASK_FAILED)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentException$Builder.build(AgentException.java:83)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.AbstractJobHandler.lambda$kill$0(AbstractJobHandler.java:211)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:211)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:200)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:130)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:435)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:900)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:634)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:98)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.create(AbstractTransformFuture.java:50)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.transformAsync(Futures.java:551)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.AbstractJobHandler.kill(AbstractJobHandler.java:202)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.JobManagerImpl.recoverAndKill(JobManagerImpl.java:145)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.MasterRequestReceiver$NormalWorkReceiver.receivedJob(MasterRequestReceiver.java:142)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.MasterRequestReceiver.pollForJobsAndTasks(MasterRequestReceiver.java:106)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.MasterRequestReceiver.pollForWork(MasterRequestReceiver.java:78)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.MasterRequestReceiver.lambda$doStart$0(MasterRequestReceiver.java:68)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$ScheduledListeningDecorator$NeverSuccessfulListenableFutureTask.run(MoreExecutors.java:623)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
======== End of Cloud Dataproc Agent Error ========
```

This is also the very last thing that can be seen in logs.
This started to happen without any changes in the spark code, for applications that were previously running for 50+ days without problems.

All clusters are in the europe-west1-d zone, global region.
All applications are written in scala.

Anyone experienced something similar? Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're saying this is fairly persistent in the last few days, I wonder if something about your input data has changed and if you were running close to 100% utilization before the failures started.

Since Compute Engine VMs don't configure a swap partition, when you run out of RAM all daemons will crash and restart.

To check this, SSH into the VM and run:

`sudo journalctl -u google-dataproc-agent`

Somewhere in the output should be JVM crash header. You can also repeat this for other Hadoop daemons like `hadoop-hdfs-namenode`. They should crash at roughly the same time.

I recommend enabling stackdriver monitoring [1] on the cluster to get RAM usage over time. If my theory is validated, you can try switching to either a `highmem` variant of the machine type you're using or a custom VM [2] with same CPUs but more RAM.

Additionally, if your jobs use Spark Streaming with Checkpointing (or can be converted to it) then consider Dataproc Restartable Jobs [3]. After such a crash Dataproc will auto-restart the job for you [4].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/stackdriver-monitoring

[2] https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/custom-machine-types

[3] https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/restartable-jobs

[4] [How to restart Spark Streaming job from checkpoint on Dataproc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008418)

Comment: Thanks! Looking at google-dataproc-agent log indeed confirmed that java run out of memory. I'll try to monitor and look it more thoroughly, maybe it is some kind of memory leak in the spark application. As for stackdriver monitoring, i'm already using it, but it seems that it doesn't support monitoring of RAM usage, or i am missing something.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up. We'll look into why RAM usage isn't reported.

Comment: I also just noticed that all the clusters that are failing using image version 1.1.34, but i also have one older cluster that's using version 1.1.29, and that one runs without problems for 60+ days. In the meantime, my clusters continue to fail, and that happens regularly after running for cca 3 and half days, regardless of amount of data they are processing.

Comment: Since I need more input to dig into this, switching conversation to "cloud-dataproc-discuss" thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to a bug in image version 1.1.34. Downgrade to image 1.1.29 and that fixes the issue.

For creating a cluster with image 1.1.29 use --image-version 1.1.29

Refer to  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-dataproc-discuss/H5Dy2vmGZ8I for more information: