# Dataproc PySpark Streaming job failing at connecting to Resource Manager

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc

My PySpark streaming job on Google Cloud Dataproc cluster is failing at initial stage, saying connecting to Resource Manager and fails.

Same code runs successfully on my local host.

Error message:

> INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to
>   ResourceManager at clustername/ Job output is complete

In this job, checkpoint file and jars sits on master to enable recovery from checkpoint directory for one time as suggested by Dennis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112171/spark-streaming-on-dataproc-throws-filenotfoundexception)